# How do I add symbols in between two horizontal lines in a table?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have difficulties adding arrow symbols in between two horizontal lines. I have the code to ad arrow that start from one horizontal line but i dont know how to make an arrow that starts in the middle.

I have attached a picture that illustrate the result I want to reach.

[image]

Thanks to @zarko I have already a code that is close to the desired result, which is given below.

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 3mm and 20mm,
        arr/.style = {draw=blue!70!black, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, very thick},
          N/.style = {font=\small, text width=60mm, align=center, inner sep=2pt},
                                ]
        % left image
        \node (n1) [N]  {Set \mbox{$r_1=0$}\\
                         Use fixed window $[0,r_2]$};
        \draw[thick]    (n1.west) -- ++ (0,-30mm)
                        (n1.east) -- ++ (0,-30mm);
                        %
        \coordinate[below=19mm of n1.west] (aux1);
        \path[arr]  (n1.east |- aux1) node[right] {$r_2$} --
                    (aux1) node[left] {$r_2$};
                    
        % right image
        \node (n2) [N, right=of n1]  
                        {Set \mbox{$r\in[0,r_1-r_2]$}\\
                         Anvend fast termineringsvindue $[r_1,r_2]$};
        \draw[thick]    (n2.west) -- ++ (0,-30mm)
                        (n2.east) -- ++ (0,-30mm);
        
                        %
        \coordinate[below=19mm of n2.west] (aux2);
        \coordinate[above=of aux2] (aux3);
        \coordinate[above=of aux3] (aux4);
        \coordinate[above=of aux4] (aux5);
        \path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux2) --
                    (aux2) node[left] {$r_1$};
        \path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux3) node[right] {$r_2$} -- ++ 
                    (-36mm,0) node[left] {$r_1$};
        \path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux4) -- node[above] {$r_w=r_2-r_1$} ++
                    (-24mm,0) node[left] {$r_1$};
                    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should give you an idea how this could be done. You can just let your arrows start at an arbitrary position. As long as you don't use `--` (or `to`) in your `\path` nothing will be drawn (oversimplification, but true in this case). So you can move to a specific point (e.g., `(aux1)` moves to the coordinate `aux1`, and `++(2,0)` moves two centimetre to the right from the current position), and start drawing once you have reached the desired point.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 3mm and 20mm,
    arr/.style = {draw=blue!70!black, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, very thick},
    N/.style = {font=\small, text width=60mm, align=center, inner sep=2pt},
  ]
  % left image
  \node (n1) [N]  {Set \mbox{$r_1=0$}\\
  Use fixed window $[0,r_2]$};
  \draw[thick]    (n1.west) -- ++ (0,-30mm)
  (n1.east) -- ++ (0,-30mm);
  %
  \coordinate[below=19mm of n1.west] (aux1);
  \path[arr]  (aux1) ++(2,0) node[right]{$r_2$} to (aux1);
  \coordinate[below=of aux1] (aux1);
  \path[arr]  (aux1) ++(4,0) node[right]{$r_2$} -- (aux1) node[left]{$r_1$};
  \coordinate[below=of aux1] (aux1);
  \path[arr]  (n1.east |- aux1) node[right] {$r_2$} -- (aux1);

  % right image
  \node (n2) [N, right=of n1]  
  {Set \mbox{$r\in[0,r_1-r_2]$}\\
  Anvend fast termineringsvindue $[r_1,r_2]$};
  \draw[thick]    (n2.west) -- ++ (0,-30mm)
  (n2.east) -- ++ (0,-30mm);

  %
  \coordinate[below=19mm of n2.west] (aux2);
  \coordinate[above=of aux2] (aux3);
  \coordinate[above=of aux3] (aux4);
  \coordinate[above=of aux4] (aux5);
  \path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux2) --
  (aux2) node[left] {$r_1$};
  \path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux3) node[right] {$r_2$} -- ++ 
  (-36mm,0) node[left] {$r_1$};
  \path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux4) -- node[above] {$r_w=r_2-r_1$} ++
  (-24mm,0) node[left] {$r_1$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I still have difficulties changing the endings of the arrows. For the right illustration how can i copy the coding for the three arrows and place them in the middel?

Comment: @Konstantin by changing both their start and end coordinate, e.g., after the `\coordinate` code you could use `\path[arr] (aux) +(4,0) -- +(2,0);` to get an error that starts 4cm right of the coordinate and ends 2cm right of the coordinate (if you use `+(x,y)` you move to that point, but don't change the point from which the next relative coordinate is calculated).